# Mapping dataframe values from another dataframe with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df1

```
df1 = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
```

and I have another df2

```
df2 = {'Name':['krish', 'jack','Tom', 'nick',]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

df2['Name'] is exactly same with df1. However, they are in a different order.

I want to fill df2['Age'] based on df1.

If I used `df2['Age'] = df1['Age']` the value of is filled but wrong.

How to map those values on df2 from df1 correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1,on='Name')
df2

    Name  Age
0  krish   19
1   jack   18
2    Tom   20
3   nick   21
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `Name` as index and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) based on `df2`:

```
df1.set_index('Name').reindex(df2.Name).reset_index()

   Name   Age
0  krish   19
1   jack   18
2    Tom   20
3   nick   21
```

---

Or for a better performance, we can use [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Categorical.html) here:

```
df1['Name'] = pd.Categorical(df1.Name, categories=df2.Name)
df1.sort_values('Name', inplace=True)
```